# Replace mysql->php->mysql with nested query

Tags: php, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with columns 'customer' and 'location' and I need to check top 10 locations visited by unique customers.

I'm ready to do the following:

1. SELECT location FROM myTable GROUP BY location
2. load results to an array (maybe a hundred of few hundreds of locations)
3. SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, tbl.location AS LOCATION FROM (SELECT DISTINCT customer FROM myTable WHERE location = location_inserted_by_php) as tbl;

Now, this sounds like a rather stupid solution, but I'm rather unacquainted with nested queries. Any help?

Thanks

Comment: So you want to combine the queries to get locations visited by Customer A lets say and then get the top 10 places they visited? You could query that information first and then parse and count it afterwards. I always have found COUNT quite slow, so i try to to use it.

Comment: I wanted to make top 10 visited location, but only to count visits from unique visitors. So, if customer A you mentioned visits the place 1000 times, it's still only 1 visit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT location,count(distinct customer) as visitors from customer_locations
GROUP BY location
ORDER BY visitors DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Gets the top 10 locations by number of unique visitors

Comment: Thank you. didn't know that I can enter distinct customer inside of count :(. Now I need a good (and rather complete) tutorial for mysql, obviously.